# opengraph - not reading my og-tags

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a solution for 3 days now, but cannot find it ...

I have this page with build in "send-button" to Facebook.

http://www.architectura.be/nieuwsdetail_new_fb_1.asp?id_tekst=2570

I have my og tags specified, but it is not working. (random image is showing, random title, ...)

Any help would be enormously apreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong, so here is a list of possibilities:

- locale: Do you really need to set a locale?.
- type: Try to use the right type. Maybe use 'article' or something like that instead of using 'movie'.
- **url**: The facebook crawler is checking the page with the url you set, 'http://...?id_tekst=2586'. When i look at the source code on that page, there are no opengraph parameters. You´re setting them on page 'http://...?id_tekst=2570'
- image: Use an absolute path to your image, e.g. 'http://domain/image.jpg'
- fb:admins: USER_ID has to be a valid userId or username (optional)

Hope that helps a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Andy is right. Let me put it another way; Facebook does not read all of the page that you specify (2570), it reads the og:url and then it looks for metadata at *that* address (2586); because that is meant to be the "canonical" or "reference" version of the page.

I don't know what you intend, so I can't tell you how to fix that.

But I will also point out that the HTML coding on your page is *extremely bad* and even when you get the URL sorted out, it's possible that Facebook will be unable to read the page correctly.

David